# How to push data to a nested Object

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, json, salesforce-id, array

I have table which has I'm iterating the Above Response to display the data in Table Format.

Column 1 has Iteration Value Of `timeSheetDate`, Column 2 has nested data object as a fields.

In column 2 Each Row i have `Plus` button. On click it need to add new Row in same `td`.Baically need to Push the object in `timesheetDetails` for the Particular field.

Below Code throw's `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined` Error.

```
<table
                            class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered slds-table_col-bordered slds-border_left slds-border_right"
                            style="width: 50%;">
                            <thead>
                                <tr class="">
                                    <th class="" style="background: #03A9F4;" scope="col">
                                        <div class="slds-align_absolute-center slds-truncate slds-text-color_inverse"
                                            style="font-size: initial;" title="Time Sheet Date">
                                            Time Sheet Date</div>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="" style="background: #03A9F4;" scope="col">
                                        <div class="slds-align_absolute-center slds-truncate slds-text-color_inverse"
                                            style="font-size: initial;" title="Regular">Time Sheet
                                            Details
                                        </div>
                                    </th>

                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <template for:each={timesheetDaysData} for:item="tsd" for:index="index">
                                    <tr class="slds-hint-parent" key={tsd.recId}>
                                        <th data-label={tsd.timeSheetDate} scope="row">
                                            <div class="slds-align_absolute-center slds-truncate"
                                                title={tsd.timeSheetDate}>
                                                {tsd.timeSheetDate}
                                            </div>
                                        </th>
                                        <td data-label="Time Sheet Details">



                                            <div class="slds-float_right slds-p-bottom_large">
                                                <lightning-button-icon icon-name="utility:add" title="Add TimeDetails"
                                                    variant="brand" icon-position="right" onclick={addNewTimeDetails}>
                                                </lightning-button-icon>
                                            </div>


                                            <template for:each={tsd.timesheetDetails} for:item="tsdtl"
                                                for:index="index">

                                                <div class="slds-grid" key={tsdtl.timeSheetDetailID}>
                                                    <div class="slds-col">
                                                        <span>
                                                            <lightning-combobox name="Project" label=""
                                                                value={tsdtl.projectName} placeholder="Select Project"
                                                                options={projectDataOptions}>
                                                            </lightning-combobox>
                                                        </span>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="slds-col slds-p-left_x-small">
                                                        <span>
                                                            <lightning-combobox name="Type" label=""
                                                                value={tsdtl.timeSheetHoursType}
                                                                placeholder="Select Type" options={typeofHoursoptions}>
                                                            </lightning-combobox>
                                                        </span>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="slds-col slds-p-left_x-small">
                                                        <span>
                                                            <lightning-input type="number" value={tsdtl.timeSheetHours}
                                                                placeholder="Hours" label=""></lightning-input>
                                                        </span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </template>
                                        </td>

                                    </tr>
                                </template>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

```
addNewTimeDetails(event) {
    this.timesheetDaysData.timesheetDetails.push({
      projectName: "",
      timeSheetDetailID: null,
      timeSheetHours: 0,
      timeSheetHoursType: ""
    });
    console.log("Enter ", this.timesheetDaysData);
  }
```

I'm returning the Response as Below fromthe Apex Controller.

```
[
    {
        "timeSheetDate": "May 11th",
        "timesheetDetails": [
            {
                "projectName": "",
                "timeSheetHours": 0,
                "timeSheetHoursType": ""
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "timeSheetDate": "May 12th",
        "timesheetDetails": [
            {
                "projectName": "",
                "timeSheetHours": 0,
                "timeSheetHoursType": ""
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "timeSheetDate": "May 13th",
        "timeSheetDateId": "a3P1I000000YANiUAO",
        "timesheetDetails": [
            {
                "projectName": "Emit CS Payroll",
                "timeSheetDetailID": "a3O1I000002IE6dUAG",
                "timeSheetHours": 4,
                "timeSheetHoursType": "Paid Time Off"
            },
            {
                "projectName": "Emit CS Payroll",
                "timeSheetDetailID": "a3O1I000002IE6YUAW",
                "timeSheetHours": 4,
                "timeSheetHoursType": "Billable Regular"
            }
        ]
    }

]
```

Answer (score 1):

`this.timesheetDaysData` is an array not an object. So you will need to search the object item in using id or some other unique value. Then you will be able to update that.

so instead of

```
this.timesheetDaysData.timesheetDetails.push()
```

It should be

```
this.timesheetDaysData[index].timesheetDetails.push()
```

or

```
 let index = this.timesheetDaysData.findIndex(element => element.Id === event.target.dataset.id);
 this.timesheetDaysData[index].timesheetDetails.push();
```